# Transfer money from Citibank to Norway TT vs Visa withdrawal

Tags: international-transfer, singapore, norway

I have an account in Singapore Citibank, and I need to transfer some money to my bank account in Norway as big as around 20K SGD.

I used to do this last year with TT and ended up paying around 50 SGD for transfer fee charged by Citibank and Norwegian's local bank. I did not have an idea whether it was a good exchange rate comparing to another method. But it was very convenient.

I want to know if there is a possibility that it would be more cost effective to do this by ATM Visa withdrawal? Unfortunately there is no Citibank ATM in Norway.

Any other suggestion?